# Passing API generated object between pages in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, model, shopping-cart

I have a API Generated list of items, and i would like to view the Items into Cart Page, Currently items are being added but not as Item object, because when i try to access one of the item Properties in the Cart page it gives me the error: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'image_URL' was called on null. Receiver null, Tried Calling: image_url.
I know am supposed to pass the selected item some how, but how should i do this?

This is the code in the main page where the Item list is being generated and view

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'cart_page.dart';
import 'cart_bloc.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'repository/item_repo.dart';
import 'models/item.dart';
import 'components/item_card.dart';

//My own Imports
import 'package:alsyed_bakeries_ecommerce/components/horizontal_list_view.dart';
import 'package:alsyed_bakeries_ecommerce/components/drawerr.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<CartBloc>(
        create: (context) => CartBloc(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Alsayed E-commerce',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.red,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Alsayed Bakeries'),
        ));
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  List<Item> _items = <Item>[];
  //final Item item;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    listenForItems();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var bloc = Provider.of<CartBloc>(context);
    int totalCount = 0;
    if (bloc.cart.length > 0) {
      totalCount = bloc.cart.values.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: null),
          new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: new Container(
                height: 150.0,
                width: 30.0,
                child: new GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => CartPage(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: new Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new IconButton(
                        icon: new Icon(
                          Icons.shopping_cart,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onPressed: null,
                      ),
                      new Positioned(
                          child: new Stack(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Icon(Icons.brightness_1,
                                  size: 20.0, color: Colors.red[700]),
                              new Positioned(
                                  top: 3.0,
                                  right: 7,
                                  child: new Center(
                                    child: new Text(
                                      '$totalCount',
                                      style: new TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 12.0,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                    ),
                                  )),
                            ],
                          )),
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
          )
        ],

      ),
      drawer: Drawerr(),
      body:Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 150,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: new Text('Categories',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          //fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        // color: Colors.grey,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20.0)), ),
                //Horizontal list
                HorizontalList(),
              ],

            ),
          ),

            Container(
              height: 600,
              child: ListView.builder(

                  itemCount: _items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ItemTile(_items[index]),
              ),
            ),


        ],
      ),
    );

  }

  void listenForItems() async {
    final Stream<Item> stream = await getItems();
    stream.listen((Item item) =>
        setState(() =>  _items.add(item))
    );
  }

}
```

And this is the code of the cart page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'cart_bloc.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'models/item.dart';
import 'main.dart';

class CartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Item item;

  CartPage({Key key, this.item}) : super(key: key);
  //CartPage(this._item);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var bloc = Provider.of<CartBloc>(context);
    var cart = bloc.cart;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Shopping Cart"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(23.0),
        itemCount: cart.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          int giftIndex = cart.keys.toList()[index];
          int count = cart[giftIndex];
          return Card(
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Container(
                height: 70,
                width: 70,
               child: Image.network(item.image_url, height: 50.0, fit: BoxFit.fill,)
              ),
              title: Text('Quantity: $count',),
             // subtitle: Text(item.name),
              trailing: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Remove'),
                color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
                elevation: 1.0,
                splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                onPressed: () {
                  bloc.clear(giftIndex);
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: new Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: ListTile(
              title: new Text("Total"),
              subtitle: new Text("232"),
            ),),
            Expanded(
              child: new MaterialButton(onPressed: (){},
              child: new Text("Check out" , style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                color: Colors.red,),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ) ,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference this https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data#4-navigate-and-pass-data-to-the-detail-screen

code snippet

```
new GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => CartPage(item: _items),
                      ),
                    );
                  }

...
class CartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Item> item;
```

Comment: But this way only the first Item in the list is being passed, the items are generated dynamically from API, so they are not fixed objects.. thank you for the link.

Comment: Because your CartPage only accept Item. if you change to List<Item>, you can pass whole _items, you can see my updated answer.